# add submodule to git project and download it content

Tags: git

I've create `.gitmodules` file with content

```
[submodule "xxxx/src/main/webapp/js/app/ui"]
    path = xxx/src/main/webapp/js/app/ui
    url = git@github.com:xxx/task-core.git
```

But how to make its content to appear in `src/main/webapp/js/app/ui`?
I did

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

But my folder is still empty.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't add the submodule via `git submodule add`?

Comment: I thought it would be done automatically. Guess I was wrong,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually adding a submodule reference to `.gitmodules`, use `git submodule add`. Clean up your .gitmodules file, and then try the following:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:xxx/task-core.git -- xxx/src/main/webapp/js/app/ui
```

Then you should see the edited `.gitmodules` as well as the submodule directory listed in `git status`.

Now would be a good time to run:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

For further reference, check out [this chapter of git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).